# Cisco ASA 5505 no NAT

Tags: nat, cisco-asa

I have a cisco asa 5505. The outside and inside IPs are private IPs so I do not want to NAT the inside IPs as they go out the Outside interface (there is a router upstream of the ASA 5505. Would I do static NATs? Or how would I pass traffic from the inside to the outside (like on a ping) without NATing the IP?

Outside e0/0 VLAN 1000 IP: 192.168.0.6 255.255.255.248

Inside e0/1 VLAN 2 IP: 192.168.0.230 255.255.255.252 (this int has a Router downstream that i want to telnet into from the Internet 192.168.0.229/30)

The Upstream router will have a 1:1 Nat mapping a public IP to the ip of the router downstream of the ASA5505.

Comment: If I were you I'd avoid using it altogether.  From memory those things are also limited to 100Mbit!  Might make a good door stop.

Comment: Well its going to a Lab network, I want to have tighter control of what makes it out of there. The upstream router of the ASA is the main production router.

Comment: https://www.fir3net.com/Firewalls/Cisco/cisco-asa-83-no-nat-nat-exemption.html ?